# Get the request headers cookie using headless chrome

Tags: cookies, google-chrome-headless

How can I return a cookie from the request headers using `headless chrome`?

This is an object from a HAR file:

```
  {
    "startedDateTime": "2017-10-16T22:52:59.382Z",
    "time": 218.02899999602226,
    "request": {
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "http://www.allstate.com/",
      "httpVersion": "HTTP/1.1",
      "headers": [
        {
          "name": "User-Agent",
          "value": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36"
        },
        {
          "name": "cookie",
          "value": "ak_bmsc=48DEF0C13393490FCEB2FDA5A4A47272D17497C42A7F0000DB37E559BE40FA5A~plKzlrqFeBqHoExIu4hYna8WskNf3a/28W7xdb5+d40hedhMehAO2ljKdjALQ8l0w5Gf9gDc761BnFguZzlCwlA0vXdhbT9NNMlKqaKc/JM4lQzMQcajdeqngg/CUUt6IyDxZhaBOv1WqcNUxJt8EVPPY3r1E3rwgQpwmQL1Eb0hPpUGHxnhzC/B9cbGKylDh/XgfiNoieQ5KjrgwQYcfnXnKZpgql4RO4lXxmjZHUj58="
        }
      ],
      "cookies": [
        {
          "name": "ak_bmsc",
          "value": "48DEF0C13393490FCEB2FDA5A4A47272D17497C42A7F0000DB37E559BE40FA5A~plKzlrqFeBqHoExIu4hYna8WskNf3a/28W7xdb5+d40hedhMehAO2ljKdjALQ8l0w5Gf9gDc761BnFguZzlCwlA0vXdhbT9NNMlKqaKc/JM4lQzMQcajdeqngg/CUUt6IyDxZhaBOv1WqcNUxJt8EVPPY3r1E3rwgQpwmQL1Eb0hPpUGHxnhzC/B9cbGKylDh/XgfiNoieQ5KjrgwQYcfnXnKZpgql4RO4lXxmjZHUj58=",
          "expires": null,
          "httpOnly": false,
          "secure": false
        }
      ]
    },
    "response": {
      "status": 301,
      "statusText": "Moved Permanently",
      "httpVersion": "HTTP/1.1",
      "headers": [
        {
          "name": "Location",
          "value": "https://www.allstate.com/"
        },
        {
          "name": "Date",
          "value": "Mon, 16 Oct 2017 22:51:06 GMT"
        },
        {
          "name": "Server",
          "value": "AkamaiGHost"
        },
      ],
      "cookies": [],
      "redirectURL": "https://www.allstate.com/",
      "headersSize": 236,
      "bodySize": 0,
      "_transferSize": 236
    }
  }
```

I am searching for a method from headless chrome that returns this part:

```
"request": {
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "http://www.allstate.com/",
      "httpVersion": "HTTP/1.1",
      "headers": [
        {
          "name": "User-Agent",
          "value": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36"
        },
        {
          "name": "cookie",
          "value": "ak_bmsc=48DEF0C13393490FCEB2FDA5A4A47272D17497C42A7F0000DB37E559BE40FA5A~plKzlrqFeBqHoExIu4hYna8WskNf3a/28W7xdb5+d40hedhMehAO2ljKdjALQ8l0w5Gf9gDc761BnFguZzlCwlA0vXdhbT9NNMlKqaKc/JM4lQzMQcajdeqngg/CUUt6IyDxZhaBOv1WqcNUxJt8EVPPY3r1E3rwgQpwmQL1Eb0hPpUGHxnhzC/B9cbGKylDh/XgfiNoieQ5KjrgwQYcfnXnKZpgql4RO4lXxmjZHUj58="
        }
      ],
    }
```

I tried to use this method https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#event-requestWillBeSent but it never shows cookies...